# Change specific font in pdf document

Tags: linux, pdf, gnu, characters

I have a PDF file, which has a buggy font (some d's, o's and q's with black color fill inside the circe) which is annoying to read.

How can i change that specific font in the whole document, keeping the file structure?

PS: I am using GNU/Linux, so i prefer a cross-plataform solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [PDFedit](http://pdfedit.cz/en/pdfedit_library.html), IIRC, it could change the font of a PDF, but it's QT3 based, so newer distros are removing it.

If you can't use that, try [this one](http://code-industry.net/pdfeditor.php), i think it also had that capability.

If they fail, try other alternatives to [Acrobat](http://alternativeto.net/software/adobe-acrobat-suite/?platform=linux) and [PDFedit](http://alternativeto.net/software/pdfedit/?platform=linux).

Comment: I didn't understood how to change it under PDFedit, and Master PDF Editor(pdfeditor) crashed when the PDF took all the system memory (3GB). Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Do you have Acrobat Pro? If you do, here's what to do:

1. Go to Tools - Advanced Editing - TouchUp Text Tool.
2. Select the text you want to change the font of.
3. Right click and select Properties
4. Should open up with the Text tab. Select the Font you want from the dropdown list.